# pip download mirror in requirements.txt or venv

Tags: python, pip

Is there a way to fix the PyPi download mirror in a requirements.txt file? or somewhere else that gets picked up automatically? I'm based in China, and it's often convenient to use an alternative mirror as the main one can be slow e.g.

```
pip config set global.index-url https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
```

Today this caused me a lot of confusion, as my Python code & requirements.txt produced unexpected and different results on different machines.

Comment: Please limit to one question. Are you asking about how to set a global option in a requirements file or about how to handle different versions in different mirrors?

Comment: @FlyingTeller as you wish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to just include

```
--index-url https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
```

in your requirements.txt file. See [the documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#global-options)

Comment: Excellent! I didn't realize the requirements.txt file syntax was basically just command line for pip separated by newlines